# Use same controller method to fill different list in scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use one controller method to fill different lists in my view.

```
var loadPlayers = function (division) {
    var year = new Date().getFullYear() - parseInt(division);
    console.log(year);
    return PlayersService.getPlayersByDate(year).then(function(response){
        return response;
    });
};
$scope.playersU20 = loadPlayers(20);
$scope.playersU18 = loadPlayers(18);
```

PlayersService

```
this.getPlayersByDate = function (year) {
    var promise = $http.get('/playerByYear/' + year).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
    return promise;
};
```

But this is not working. It just works when I remove the return statements and just do `$scope.playersU20 = response;`. But this does not allow me to re-use the function. I hope I made myself clear.

Thank you

Comment: You have 4 return statements. Which one do you refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `then` function returns a promise, so you'll need to update the scope in the success function invoked on promise fulfilment:

```
loadPlayers(20).then(function(players) { $scope.playersU20 = players; });
loadPlayers(18).then(function(players) { $scope.playersU18 = players; });
```

I would refactor to remove `loadPlayers` - it seems redundant when you can just use your players service directly in the controller if you used years rather than years ago. If you also need years ago, then add it as an additional function on your players service. You'll also want to add error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `loadPlayers()` function as following. The one you did on the question is not a re-usable function in javascript. I provide you a link to learn know about how to properly declare function in JavaScript. It will give you a better understanding not only just know how to make functions in Javascript, and also talk about the scope of functions. [JavaScript Function Tutorial](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)

```
function loadPlayers (division) {
  var year = new Date().getFullYear() - parseInt(division);
  console.log(year);
  return PlayersService.getPlayersByDate(year).then(function(response){
    return response;
  });
};
$scope.playersU20 = loadPlayers(20);
$scope.playersU18 = loadPlayers(18);
```